# In PHP 7, How can I display results that have a specific word in the title?

Tags: php, filter

just want to say thanks to this community for bailing me out countless times. Today I am trying to create a template override in a Joomla component to only display results that have "DE" in the title when the URL contains "/de/". I've tried a few things, but keep getting blank results. Here is what I have so far:

```
$keywords = " DE";
$title = JHtml::_('link', $link, $item->title); // Gets Pathway Title
if ((strpos($item, "DE") || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "de")) == false) {

    $item = $displayData;

} else {

    $item = array_filter($displayData, function (array $item) use ($keywords) {
        return array_key_exists('title', $item) && $item['title'] === $keywords;
    });
}
```

Not sure how to get titles that contain " DE" at the end. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Should the first `$item` be `$title`?

Comment: Tried this, did not work either, is this what you meant?
} else {

$item = array_filter($displayData, function (array $title) use ($keywords) {
    return array_key_exists('title', $item) && $item['title'] === $keywords;
});

Comment: My question was about `strpos($item, "DE")`. Should that be `strpos($title, "DE")`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test each `strpos()` result separately, not combine them with `||`. You also have to use `===` or `!==` when testing the result of `strpos()`, because loose comparison will treat `0 == false` as true.

It's also easier to understand if you use positive conditions rather than negatives.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "de")) !== false && strpos($item, "DE") !== false) {
    $item = array_filter($displayData, function (array $item) use ($keywords) {
        return array_key_exists('title', $item) && strpos($item['title'], $keywords) !== false;
    });
} else {
    $item = $displayData;
}
```

Comment: I restructured the code the way you suggest, the REQUEST_URI is working fine, it is the 'filtered results' I'm still not getting. Just returns blank boxes. 
$item = array_filter($displayData, function (array $item) use ($keywords) {
        return array_key_exists('title', $item) && $item['title'] === $keywords;
    });

Comment: You have a space at the beginning of `$keywords`. Do the titles have a space?

Comment: You're matching the title exactly, not looking for a substring.

Comment: AHA! Ok, how do I search for a string and not the entire title? strpos?

Comment: Of course, just like you do in the `if`.

Comment: How could you not know that? Didn't you write `strpos($item, "DE")` for the same reason?

Comment: I tried that first, but could get any results with it. I'm not a PHP coder, I'm trying to make a plugin do something it wasn't meant to do, without creating a 'hack' in the Component. strpos didn't work the first or last time I tried it. I must be formatting it wrong.

Comment: I edited the answer. As I mentioned above, take the space out of `$keywords` if you don't require that in the title.

Comment: Edit the question and show sample values of the variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246355/discussion-between-charlie-trig-and-barmar).